# Autofac injects objects with the same reference

Tags: c#, autofac

I keep getting reference to the same object. As you can see in constructor there are two objects with the same type. I would expect to get two different instances but whenever I set the property of _player1, the _player2 is being set accordingly with the same value. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

IoC container

```
public static void ConfigureContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
    builder.RegisterInstance<IPlayer>(new Player());
    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

Controller constructor

```
public FlagGameController(IPlayer player1, IPlayer player2)
{
    _player1 = player1;
    _player2 = player2;
    _currentPlayer = player1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you say

```
 builder.RegisterInstance
```

you are actually setting it up to always return the same instance. If you want to return a different instance every time, use

```
 builder.RegisterType<Player>().As<IPlayer>().InstancePerDependency();
```

ref - http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-dependency

Answer (score 0):

The `RegisterInstance` method tells *Autofac* to register only a single instance of `IPlayer` inside the container, it allows you to register a singleton.

The following code

```
builder.RegisterInstance<IPlayer>(new Player());
```

is equivalent to

```
builder.RegisterInstance<IPlayer>(new Player()).SingleInstance();
```

or 
    builder.RegisterType().As().SingleInstance();

See [Registration Concepts - Instance components](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#instance-components) for more information.

If you want to have more than one instance, don't use the `RegisterInstance` method but use another registration method. For example

```
builder.Register(c => new Player()).As<IPlayer>();
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<Player>().As<IPlayer>();
```

*Autofac* use the *InstancePerDependency* method by default which configure the registration to create a new instance each time it is resolved.